# How do I prevent Visual Studio 2015's debugger from evaluating static properties with side effects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, properties, side-effects

I have a singleton class that lazy creates its instance when a property is first called (property side effect).

```
namespace singletontest2
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using MySingleton = Singleton<MyClass>;

    public class MyClass
    {
        private int val = 42;

        public MyClass()
        {
        }
    }

    public static class Singleton<T> where T : new()
    {
        private static T t;

        public static bool IsNull
        {
            get
            {
                return t == null;
            }
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        public static T Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (t == null)
                    t = new T();
                return t;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = MySingleton.IsNull;
            var d = MySingleton.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

If I place a break point in the `Instance` property getter and on the `var d` line, the `t` member will already be initialized when I step into the `Instance` getter.

If I move the break point from `var d` to the next line, the `t` is null when I debug into the `Instance` getter.

I was under the impression the `DebuggerBrowsable` attribute would prevent this but it seems to not make any difference.

HOWEVER, if I eliminate the `using MySingleton = Singleton<MyClass>;` above and call `Singleton<MyClass>.Instance;` instead of `MySingleton.Instance;`, then the member `t` is null when I enter the `Instance` getter regardless of `DebuggerBrowsable` which is what I want.

Why is the `using` directive enabling the debugger to evaluate that property before the code is actually executed?

Comment: _"If I place a break point in the Instance property getter and on the var d line, the t member will already be initialized when I step into the Instance getter"_ -- I cannot reproduce your claimed behavior, with the code you've provided. The value of `t` is `null` when I step into the `Instance` getter. Since your example above has a `MainWindow` class, the code for which you failed to provide, it seems likely there is something else in your code, besides what you've shared, causing what you observe. Please fix the question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: (Note: I'm using VS2017)

Comment: The original example code was using a default WPF project with no other code. I changed the example to be a console app instead of a WPF project but I still see the same behavior as before. Perhaps it's a bug in VS 2015?

Comment: Do you have a watch set on `MySingleton.Instance` in the Watch window?

Comment: No, but it does show up in the Auto window unavoidably.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question?

Comment: That'll do it, too.

Comment: But removing the `using` directive eliminates the issue. The Auto window isn't completely to blame here. And that's not something I have control over.

Comment: I think there are votes to close because it's technically not a programming question, but rather knowledge of a development tool, which to me is a bit nit-picky...

Comment: @lesscode and also incorrect, since development tools are explicitly on-topic. Note there's only one close vote as yet, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Well, you can close it :-) (I didn't have it open when I first tried to reproduce, but a watch was able to repro it, and the Autos window is basically the same animal).

Comment: I don't think telling every developer to close the Auto/Watch windows when debugging this code is a viable solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761668/how-to-avoid-triggering-properties-while-debugging

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925886/c-vs-2008-debugger-executing-property-code

Comment: @cppguy, What about this issue now? Is it related to the debugging settings like Iesscode's suggestion?

Comment: lesscode's suggestion of changing settings does not seem reasonable to me even if it does work. It would require all developers looking at this code forever to turn off a very valuable feature in the debugger. The problem is `[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]` doesn't work when the `using` directive is used. That's a conflict between the language and the dev environment. The correct answer was unfortunately to not use a property and just add a method instead since the property had side effects.

Comment: @cppguy, Do you mean that you have resolved this issue?

Comment: Not to my satisfaction no. I should be able to use the using directive and DebuggerBrowsable attribute together. I would rather not have to create a method instead of a property. I have worked around the issue but my question was not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off **Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls** as advocated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx